# I want to run the terminal command n nodejs language

Tags: node.js, exec

### Creating a Nodejs server code, I'd like to turn on a new terminal window and enter a command.

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec

exec('gnome.terminal', (err,out,stderr) => {
console.log(out)
});`
```

### I'd like to open a new window with the code above and enter a command.

```
(new) 1 terminal -> command : roslaunch rpliadr_ros rplidar.launch
(new) 2 terminal -> command : roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look up [shell.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenTerm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-term) module. It's do exactly what you want - open terminal, and execute.

It has both functions for individual terminals: ( consider to use them only if you sure they exists in your **PATH** ).

```js
const { VT } = require('open-term')
VT.linux.xterm('ls -l') // Runs "ls -l" command in xterm.
VT.linux.guake('ls -l') // Runs "ls -l" command in guake.
```

And configurable function which automatically determines terminal to use:

```js
const { VTexec } = require('open-term')
VTexec('help') // "help" command works both on bash and cmd.
```